# export views data to text file in the background

Tags: views, rules, importing-exporting

I am using [views data export](http://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to generate a text file and that works perfectly. but instead of asking me to save it to my local computer.

What I want to do is save it directly on the server, I would like to run this is the background if possible as large amounts of data take time to generate.
Ideally I would like to run this for each user in the background on cron run so I presume I will need to setup some batch job to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think you can set a cron job on server. You just need to add a drush command in crontab file. Drush command :

```
drush views-data-export [view-name] [display-id] [output-file]
```

[Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) provides this drush command.

**Edit :**

1. If you don't have drush installed on your server then you can take the idea from code of `views_data_export.drush.inc`.

Or :

2. In simple way you can run the code following in hook_cron :

   $output = views_embed_view('ViewName', 'views_data_export_1');
   file_unmanaged_save_data($Output , 'private://output.xls', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

As per https://www.drupal.org/node/1875456#comment-7524421.

Comment: I don't have access to drush on the server so i cant do that sadly :(

Comment: @Jerry updated my answer.